# How do I get axes labels in a DensityPlot?

Tags: plotting

I am trying

```
DensityPlot[output, {input1, 0.41, 1.16}, {input2, -0.4, 0.37}, 
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  Mesh -> 16, 
  AxesLabel -> {"input1", "input2"}]
```

but the addition of `AxesLabel -> {"input1", "input2"}` does not label the axes as usual, is there an alternative way or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `FrameLabel` instead. `AxesLabel` requires the origin to be present (and `Axes -> True` if you move the origin with `AxesOrigin`, unless `AxesLabel -> Automatic`).